# Errors with one Java Project, while the other runs without error

Tags: java

I'm sorry if this is a cryptic ask but, I'm brand new to Java and wondering if I'm missing something obvious here. Why would Project1 not be running, while Project 2 runs without any errors? Let me know of any other information I can provide!

[image]

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Program1
{
    //***************************************************************
    //
    //  Method:       main
    // 
    //  Description:  The main method of the program
    //
    //  Parameters:   String array
    //
    //  Returns:      N/A 
    //
    //**************************************************************
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       // declare variables here
       double amount = 32500.00;
       double twiceMonth = 24;
       double biWeekly = 26;
       
       developerInfo();
    
       // Enter more statements here
       twiceMonth = amount/24;
       biWeekly = amount/26;
       
       //to format the value to two decimal places use decimalformat class
       DecimalFormat dformat=new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    
       System.out.println("Annual Salary           = $" + dformat.format(amount));
       System.out.println("When paid twice a month = $" + dformat.format(twiceMonth));
       System.out.println("When paid bi-weekly     = $" + dformat.format(biWeekly));
    }
    
    //***************************************************************
    //
    //  Method:       developerInfo
    // 
    //  Description:  The developer information method of the program
    //
    //  Parameters:   None
    //
    //  Returns:      N/A 
    //
    //**************************************************************
    public static void developerInfo()
    {
       System.out.println("Name:    Erin Oefelein");
       System.out.println("Course:  ITSE 2321 Object-Oriented Programming");
       System.out.println("Program: One \n");

    } // End of developerInfo
}
```

Comment: Project 1 & 2 are with the same code?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Switch to the "Problems" view and check what it says there, then fix that.

Comment: The code you have posted works fine, I just tested it. You might want to refresh the project or something, see if that helps. If not, delete the project that doesn't work and keep the one that does (if they are the same), or create a new one (if they are different).

Comment: As others are saying this is an issue with your project or with your IDE. If you look in Eclipse above, can you see how the Project 1 folder and everything under it has a red X on it? That indicates Eclipse can't find or access these files/directories. If you can't figure out a simple fix, create a new project and a new Program.java file in that new project and then just copy and paste the contents of the current project's Program.java to the new file and delete the old project.

Comment: @Ismail No, Project 2, is different, but it runs without error is the point I was trying to get across!:)
I'm not sure why, but the Problems view showed that Eclipse wasn't recognizing the final closing } to close the Program1 class. I copied everything to a new script and it works fine. Thank you everyone for your input!!!